# Error while starting docky

Tags: unity, docky

I installed Docky today, and after a little bit of messing around, i closed it from the default launcher that Ubuntu has (i'm on 12.04.2), and after that whenever i click on the docky icon, nothing happens. It just doesnt load, when i tried running it from the terminal, it ran perfectly with all my settings intact, but that's tedious, to run it from the terminal each time ie.

Any fix for this that is known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i've figured it out and i reckon that should close this topic. for anyone interested or for future reference, that error that i experienced was solved as follows-

Basically, Docky wasn't starting again because despite shutting it down form the Unity launcher, its process was still active, so by shutting it down with the system monitor tool, the process was terminated once in for all and that allowed me to run Docky again.